# IOS Xcode - Error in ProgressHUD package installing via Cocoapods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I was installing this package via cocoapods but as soon as I try to run the project I'm getting this error. Please let me know what shall I do.

The link to the package is https://github.com/relatedcode/ProgressHUD

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

In theory the solution could be to Replace `dismissHUD()` with `self.dismissHUD()`. But in fact you're using a rather old version of Xcode, I think. You may have installed a version of ProgressHUD that is too new. See their GitHub page, they have instructions about this (though it would be better to bring Xcode all the way up to date).